# How to free memory of c++ WinRT value structs

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, c++-cx, winrt-component

Do I have to, and how do I, free memory from a value struct created in a Windows Runtime Component that has been returned to a managed C# project?

I declared the struct

```
// Custom struct
public value struct PlayerData
{
    Platform::String^ Name;
    int Number;
    double ScoringAverage;
};
```

like

```
auto playerdata = PlayerData();
playerdata.Name = ref new String("Bla");
return playerdata;
```

I'm new with freeing memory and haven't got a clue how and when to free this.
Anyone?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ FYI, WinRT = [c++-cx], not [c++-cli]

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski sorry for the mixup. Any comments how to free memory from objects that cross the boundry between the windows runtime component and a C# project? (like my PlayerData)

Comment: no worries, I just pointed out to another editor that he added the wrong tag. I myself have no experience with WinRT and only saw your question because of the C++/CLI tag, so I'm afraid I can't help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a *value struct* is assigned to another variable, its members are **copied**, so that both variables have their own copy of the data (see [Value classes and structs (C++/CX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699861.aspx)). The same rule applies, when returning a value struct from a function.

In your code you have `playerdata`, an object of type `PlayerData` with automatic storage duration. The `return` statement makes a copy of `playerdata` (including the `Platform::String^` member), and returns this copy to the caller. After that, `playerdata` goes out of scope, and is automatically destroyed.

In other words: The code you posted works as expected. You do not have to explicitly free any memory.

Comment: and andy, many thanks for the answers, very clear. BUT it turned out I needed classes instead of a struct, to get them From runtime component to my c# project. Do i need to free memory (classes) that I created in the runtime component that got back to the c# project? like: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-wp-demo/blob/master/PocketSphinxRntComp/SpeechRecognizer.h#L32

Comment: @Toinedb: If you have another question, you should click the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: OK, will do that. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The playerdata struct is created on the stack; 'new' was not called. It was not created on the heap, so there is no memory that needs to be freed.